# How to detect if layout was rendered before partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem. I have an rails webpage and I am loading all the pages with jquery.

It all works as expected except when I try to access an URL that is rendered partial from the browser - I type in the browser www.mywebsite.something/aPageThatIsRenderedPartial.

As expected it is rendered partial and the layout is not loaded.

So my question is can I do some rails magic to render all if main layout is not loaded?

I will try to make this as clear as I can with my limited English skills:) :

Is it possible to something like this in the controller

If mainLayout is not loaded
then render :layout => true
else render :layout => false

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can pass the :layout option to your render methods.

Comment: What do you mean by mainLayout? Could you explain it a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use different `respond_to` blocks:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # general HTML request
  format.json { render :layout => false } # AJAX request
end
```

Don't forget to specify format for your AJAX request as JSON, or change url to `www.mywebsite.something/aPageThatIsRenderedPartial.json` for JQuery Get request.